# Override antd Select's search functionality

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I can't seem to override antd Select's search functionality. It seems to ignore the state change triggered by `onSearch` callback function. I have created a sandbox of my code: [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-mccarthy-pbmvw)

Am I missing something? I'm quite sure the state changes are reflected immediately but the loop seems to be using something else -- not the services state. Or it's just not possible to override it?